# Two column layout - move right column to next line if left column width is to small

Tags: html, css

I have a wrapper and two elements inside: left div and right div. The left div contains only text which can be very long. The right div contain image which is loaded asynchronous and we don't know its width:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="left">TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT</div>
    <div id="right">IMAGE</div>
</div>
```

I want to display everything in this way:

```
+-----------------------------+
|                             | 
|  #wrapper                   |
|                             | 
|  +----------+  +--------+   |
|  |          |  |        |   |
|  | #left    |  | #right |   |
|  |          |  |        |   |
|  +----------+  +--------+   |
|                             |
+-----------------------------+
```

To do this I prepared this CSS:

```
#wrapper{
    width: 600px;
    display: inline-block;
}
#left{
    float: left;
    width: 400px;
}
#right{
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
}
```

Now I want to add some responsive to this layout. The minimal width of left div should be 200px, so if the image on right is wider than 400px it should go to the next line and left div should grow to the 100% of wrapper in this way:

```
+-----------------------------+
|                             | 
|  #wrapper                   |
|                             | 
|  +----------------------+   |
|  |                      |   |
|  | #left                |   |
|  |                      |   |
|  +----------------------+   |
|                             |
|      +--------------+       |
|      |              |       |
|      |    #right    |       |
|      |              |       |
|      +--------------+       |
|                             |
+-----------------------------+
```

How can I do this without using JavaScript?

I found this solution: http://jsfiddle.net/fxWg7/1865/ and the only difference that I need is when left div is to small, then the right div should go to next line instead of the left div.

It should be something like this:

```
#left.width = #wrapper.width - #right.width;
if (#left.width < 200px) {
  #left.width = 100%;
  #right move to new line;
} else {
  display #left div on left side and #right div next to #left div
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I added float:left to both your divs see http://jsfiddle.net/fxWg7/1866/

```
#wrapper {
height: auto;
overflow: hidden;
}

#right {
width: auto;
float: right;
background: #aafed6;
}

#left {
float: left; 
background: #e8f6fe;
width: auto;
overflow: hidden;
min-width: 200px;
max-width:300px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but this is not what I really need. I cannot define max-width of left div because I don't know this value.

Comment: @Temp Instead of max-width you can use width try if that's enough

Comment: #left.width = #wrapper.width - #right.width. I don't know #right.width so I cannot calculate #left.width. It has to be automatically calculated by web browser.

Comment: @Temp is it okay to use percentage?

Comment: yes, it's ok. You can use % or any other value, it doesn't matter for me.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a css with some highlighting to answer your question here: http://jsfiddle.net/ericnjanga/kexn9ys6/.
Please let me know if its works for you.

```
/* Mobile first:
1) We apply no widths to  #wrapper, #left and #right, 
they are divs and span 100% naturally.
2) The #left which has a higher position in the DOM will naturally be on top
*/
#wrapper{
overflow: auto; /*helps contains floating children*/
}
#left{}
#right{}


/*
Mobile viewport only: We apply a "max-width: 100%" to "#right img" in order to maintain 
its natural width as long as the layout is wider but, to make it fit 
if the layout gets smaller */
@media (max-width: 599px) {  
#right img{
/* maintain img natural width as long as the layout is wider but
spans 100% when the layout gets smaller */
max-width : 100%;
}
}


/* Higher viewports:
After that breaking point, set the wrapper width and make sure the right image scales up and down with the layout */
@media (min-width: 600px) {
#wrapper{
margin: 0 auto; /* centers all elements on the page */
width: 600px;
}

/* It is better to set #left and #right widths in % */
#left{
float: left;
width: 60%; 
}
#right{
float: left;
width: 40%; 
}
#right img{ 
width: 100%;
height: inherit;
}
}
```

Comment: Very good solution, but it will be nice if it is possible to not resize image but display it in original size. For example when I change image size to 500x150 (instead of 250x150) the left div should shrink and right div should grow without changing css. At the moment the image width is always resizing to 250.

Comment: Based on what you say, the image is dynamic and any variation of it size affect #left width. There might be some css solutions out there, but I will use a javascript listener at this level if I were you.